# Trouble with expression tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, expression

I am currently trying to figure out an algorithm for an expression tree. The strings I will get currently will be like `Hello+12+World` or `A2-12-A3-14`. The strings will have the same operators in it. With my algorithm currently the last operand is not being put into the tree. I have looked online, and I'm having a hard time understanding how to make it work properly.

```cs
Stack<BaseNode> TreeStack = new Stack<BaseNode>();
BaseNode temp1 = new BaseNode();
BaseNode temp2 = new BaseNode();
for (int i = 0; i < tree.Length; i++)
{
    VariableNode varNode = new VariableNode();
    NumericalNode numNode = new NumericalNode();
    if (CheckExpressions(tree[i])) // if the character is an operator
    {
        OperatorNode expression = new OperatorNode(tree[i]);
        temp1 = TreeStack.Pop();
        if (TreeStack.Count != 0)
        {
            temp2 = TreeStack.Pop();
        }
        expression.Right = temp1;
        expression.Left = temp2;

        TreeStack.Push(expression);
    }
    else if (!CheckExpressions(tree[i]))
    {
        if (Char.IsLetter(tree[i]))
        {
            while (Char.IsLetter(tree[i])) // for the variable node
            {
                varNode.name += tree[i];
                if (i + 1 == tree.Length)
                {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            TreeStack.Push(varNode);
            if (i + 1 != tree.Length)
            {
                i--;
            }
        }
        else if (Char.IsDigit(tree[i])) // for constant value
        {
            int zero = 0; // for appending the numbers to combine them
            while (Char.IsDigit(tree[i]))
            {
                if (zero == 0)
                {
                    zero = tree[i] - '0';
                }
                else
                {
                    zero = int.Parse(zero.ToString() + tree[i].ToString());
                }
                if (i < tree.Length)
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if (i + 1 != tree.Length)
            {
                i--;
            }
            numNode.number = zero;
            TreeStack.Push(numNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can search for Polish notation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you understand you are missing the second operand because as soon as you see an operator, you try to pop the stack for 2 values. In example you have given its easy to see that it will never be the case (that stack will have 2 variables, since the operator is binary). So you should some how store the second variable and operator and try to evaluate it at some later point. Below algo might be helpful, do understand it is a basic one for simple operators.

1. Start with 2 stacks, one of variables, and one of operators.
2. Before pushing an operator on the operator stack, check for the priority/precedence. If the priority of existing operator on top of the stack is higher or equal to the one you are about to push then start popping the stack for operator and the variables.
3. Finally when you have gone through the entire string then check your stack for any operator left behind, finish the evaluation of that and you should have the end results.

In 2*3+4, when you reach + you will have 2,3 in one stack and * in another. Now on trying to push +, you will see the existing * in the stack in higher priority, so pop it, since its a binary operator pop the 2 variables, build an expression evaluate it and push on the variable stack (since the result of evaluation will be a variable/number) and then again see if there is any more operator with higher priority on the stack.

Adding a solution, please do keep in mind:
1. Operator precedence/ what kind of operator (unary/binary)/ whether it is symmetric/non-symmetric (+ is symmetric but power is not) will play important role.

Try not to modify i variable inside the loop, sooner or later you will run into trouble.

The code given works only for the 2 example given, and the portion to check for priority is blank but could be filled on the basis of existing code.

You will need to modify your variable naming loigc, in case of mixed names like 'A2' your current logic will fail.

```
string tree = "AB-12-AC-14";

            Stack<BaseNode> TreeStack = new Stack<BaseNode>();
            Stack<BaseNode> TreeStack1 = new Stack<BaseNode>();
            BaseNode temp1 = new BaseNode();
            BaseNode temp2 = new BaseNode();
            for (int i = 0; i < tree.Length; i++)
            {
                VariableNode varNode = new VariableNode();
                NumericalNode numNode = new NumericalNode();
                if (CheckExpressions(tree[i])) // if the character is an operator
                {
                    OperatorNode expression = new OperatorNode(tree[i]);

                    //check priority should pass the current operator to really check for priority
                    if (CheckPriority() || TreeStack1.Count == 0)
                    {
                        TreeStack1.Push(expression);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // assuming binary operators only
                        temp1 = TreeStack.Pop();
                        temp2 = TreeStack.Pop();
                        expression.Right = temp1;
                        expression.Left = temp2;
                        TreeStack.Push(expression);
                        // need to check if there are more operators on stack1 are they higher priority then current operator
                        // if they are then pop them and apply them too
                    }
                }
                else if (!CheckExpressions(tree[i]))
                {
                    if (Char.IsLetter(tree[i]))
                    {
                        while (Char.IsLetter(tree[i])) // for the variable node
                        {
                            varNode.name += tree[i];
                            if (i + 1 == tree.Length)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        TreeStack.Push(varNode);
                        if (i + 1 != tree.Length)
                        {
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (Char.IsDigit(tree[i])) // for constant value
                    {
                        int zero = 0; // for appending the numbers to combine them
                        while (i < tree.Length && Char.IsDigit(tree[i])) // need to check for length otherwise index will go out of bounds
                        {
                            if (zero == 0)
                            {
                                zero = tree[i] - '0';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                zero = int.Parse(zero.ToString() + tree[i].ToString());
                            }
                            if (i < tree.Length)
                            {
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (i + 1 != tree.Length)
                        {
                            i--;
                        }
                        numNode.number = zero;
                        TreeStack.Push(numNode);
                    }
                }
            }

            // finish any remaining operators and push the final expression on the stack
            while (TreeStack1.Count!=0)
            {
                OperatorNode expression1 = new OperatorNode(((OperatorNode)TreeStack1.Pop()).v);
                expression1.Right = TreeStack.Pop();
                expression1.Left = TreeStack.Pop();
                TreeStack.Push(expression1);
            }
```

Comment: "If the priority ... is higher ...", wouldn't *greater or equal* also be valid? Minor change, but would prevent building up an unnecessarily huge stack for something like `1 + 1 + 1 + ...` In fact, it could only be as large as the number of operators (constant, so constant space for *that* stack).

Comment: Thanks @DillonDavis, you are correct, updated the ans

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate this